# Certain page states not bookmarkable

Tags: ember.js

[This JSBin](http://jsbin.com/erafor/3#/companies) has `new`, `edit`, `list` page states for a `Company` model.

All page states except the `edit` one are bookmarkable, i.e. a page reload restores the page in the same state based on the URL.

Not sure why the edit state does not restore on page reload.

Comment: This bug got fixed in RC1

Answer (score 1):

This bug is caused by a known Ember issue documented [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2026) and [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2052).

Workaround is [this](http://jsbin.com/erafor/10/edit)

If you too had this problem please +1 it so that it gets some attention.